# Closed Subset of ${ L }^{ p }$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I'd like to show that the set
$$
S:=\left\{ f:X\rightarrow R:\quad f\quad \mu -\mathrm{measurable},\quad \int_{ X } { f }^{ 2 }d\mu \le 1 \right\}
$$
is closed in ${ L }^{ p }(d\mu )$, where $X$ is an arbitrary set and $\mu$ a finite measure on the sigma algebra $\Sigma \subset { 2 }^{ X }$.

First of all is it correct that this given set is the closed unit ball in ${ L }^{ 2 }$? I tried going with the standard definition and tried to show that our set contains all its limits points but I am having struggels to define arbitrary sequences in this space. Could someone offer a hint.

Comment: you have $2$ instead of $p$. Also, it's obviously true by the sequential version of closed-ness.

Comment: Are you sure about the 2? If it's $p$, then the answer is trivial. If it is $2$ it is interesting.

Comment: Thank for all your answers. Yes i'm sure about the squared Integral. So the statement is that the Closed unit ball of ${L}^2$ is closed in ${L}^p$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$d_p(f,g)=\|f-g\|_{L^p}=\left(\int_X |f-g|^p\,d\mu\right)^{1/p}$ is a distance on $L^p(X,\mu)$; this follows from the [Minkowski inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality).

Your set is $B(0,1)=\{f\in L^p: d_p(f,0)\leq 1\}$ and it's a general fact that closed balls are, indeed, closed. This is just an immediate consequence of the definition of a topology induced by a metric.

**Fact.** In a metric space $(X,d)$, any "closed ball" $D(x_0,r)=\{x\in X:d(x,x_0)\leq r\}$ is closed in the induced topology.

*Proof.* Take $x\notin D(x_0,r)$. Then $d(x,x_0)>r$. Take $0<\delta<d(x,x_0)-r$. Then I claim that $B(x,\delta)\subset D(x_0,r)^c$. Indeed, if $y\in B(x,\delta)$, then
$$
d(y,x_0)\geq d(x,x_0)-d(y,x)> d(x,x_0)-\delta > r.
$$
This means that $D(x_0,r)^c$ is open, which is equivalent to the thesis.

Comment: I don't think it is just by definition. You have to prove it (but it is very easy to prove it).

Comment: @mathworker21 Well, yeah... but still... I rephrased it however

Comment: It doesn't make a difference to people like me and you, who know the subject, but it might make a difference to a beginner.

Comment: @mathworker21 happy now? :)

Comment: Is it even possible to use the Minkowski inequality when going from ${L}^2$ to ${L}^p$?? (sorry maybe a dump question but im not very familiar with this topic)

Comment: Oh wait, we might have a problem here: do you really want to show that $\{\|f\|_2\leq 1\}$ is closed in $L^p$, for $p\neq2$?

Comment: Well then in that case my answer is not quite spot on. For $p\geq 2$ the statement is correct because $f\mapsto \int_X f^2\,d\mu$ is a continuous function in $L^p$. For $p<2$ it's false. But I have to go now. I leave you in the hands of @mathworker21 ;-)

Comment: Yes im sure unless there is a mistake in my book. For p<2 its the other way around e.g  unit ball of ${L}^2$ is closed in ${L}^1$?

Comment: If $p\leq q$, $f\mapsto\|f\|_p^p$ is continuous in $L^q$, so the (closed) unit ball of $L^p$ intersected with $L^q$ is a closed set of $L^q$. The unit ball of $L^p$ is not contained in $L^q$.

Comment: Conversely, the (closed) unit ball of $L^q$ (which) is contained in $L^p$, is not closed in $L^p$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\left(f_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ be a sequence in the involved set with converges in $\mathbb L^p$ to some $f$. Extract a subsequence $\left(f_{n_k}\right)_{k\geqslant 1}$ which converges almost everywhere to $f$. Using Fatou's lemma, we obtain 
$$
\int_Xf^2\mathrm d\mu=\int_X\liminf_{k\to +\infty}  f_{n_k}^2\mathrm d\mu\leqslant
\liminf_{k\to +\infty} \int_X f_{n_k}^2\mathrm d\mu \leqslant 1$$
hence $f$ is also an element of the consider set.

Comment: it almost seems to easy to be true, a question that came in to my mind was if it is possible for a sequence to converge in our set or generally ${L}^2$ but not in ${L}^p$